# Safari context menu search extension

Tags: safari

Does safari has an extension like [this Chrome extension called Context Menu Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/context-menu-search/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga?hl=en)? It enables user to search highlighted text from the context menu.

It should be something like this:[image]

Answer (score 3):

I needed something similar too!

So look up: [CustomSearch](https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.sidetree.CustomSearch-S64NDGV2C5). It's highly adaptable by using the integrated CustomSearch Entry Editor.

"CustomSearch allows you to easily send the selected text to one of up to eight search engines — right from the toolbar or a contextual menu. CustomSearch includes search entries for Wikipedia, Google, Bing, and Amazon."

Comment: It is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

## Mac Services

Not at the Safari-level, but on MacOS one can add custom context menu [**Services**](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-services-in-apps-mchlp1012/mac) that are context sensitive. I do this to add arbitrary search engines for any selected text (from any application).

## Steps

1. Open Automator.
2. Choose **File > New**.
3. Select **Quick Action**, then click **Choose** button.
4. Create the following workflow, replacing the search URL (currently shows DuckDuckGo search):

[image]

5. Save the Action with the name you wish to appear in Context Menu (e.g., "Search DuckDuckGo").
6. Try it out. Select some text in Safari or elsewhere, right-click, go to **Services**, and select your custom search.

Answer (score 0):

It has built-in Dictionary & Search with... on the right-click menu

[image]

I think the Search with… defaults to whatever your chosen search engine is.

The dictionary can also be triggered using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd>  in many other apps/text areas.

Comment: I've added an screenshot of what I am looking for. I hope i can choose from search engines from the menu.